# Porting Java ME to Android (working with files)

Tags: java, android, java-me

I'm trying to port a `Java ME` application to Android.
Since I'm not a Java developer I'm having some issues to resolve.

1. Working with files

   ```
   FileConnection fconn = null;
   fconn = (FileConnection)Connector.open(fileName, Connector.READ);
   InputStream inputStream = null;
   inputStream = fconn.openInputStream();
   return inputStream;
   ```

How can I do this in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  FileInputStream fIn = null;
  try{

   char[] inputBuffer = new char[1024];
   String data = null;
   fIn = openFileInput(“public.dat”);

   return fIn;

}catch(IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace(System.err);

}
```

Comment: Answer is OK, but why do you need a `data` and `inputBuffer` here?

Comment: im getting The method openFileInput(String) is undefined for the type MyClass. What am i missing?

Comment: ps: this is used in static method on private class

Comment: @no9 `openFileInput` is a method on `Context`.  You will need to pass a `Context` into your static method in order to use the above code.